# Request on Soa, SoapUI, SaaS and Web services

Tags: service, soa, saas, soapui

I recently moved south to Bangalore and I am working for a large software integrator mainly testing. My project team is working on web service project. We plan to use an open source software like soapUI now. Are you able to point me to online and offline resources/trainings that can help me and friends get up to speed with this technology.

All the help group members can provide in this regard is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rajesh Ahuja

Answer (score 2):

There are several online resources available for these technologies. Just google for it. I also suggest that you look up some of the quality indormation on www.soapui.org that cover it in detail.

Also recommend your attending Introduction to soapUI Training course on how to thoroughly test Web and REST services because it has a lot of hands-on lab work. When I spoke to Schnieder in Bangalore for Saltmarch BT Summit, he said the training covers how to use soapUI to test SOA, Web and REST services for scalability, performance and reliability.

Saltmarch also does an Advanced soapUI Pro training course. For training details check www.saltmarchi.com.

Good luck,
Dheeraj